# fade separate divs

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout

Not sure how to do this but I have tried to make this work but the menu buttons jump up and down when I put in the `fadeOut`.

I'm trying to adjust the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` speed of the divs without the buttons and information jumping around.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item-1 content-item">
    I am the 1st image content
</div>

<div class="item-2 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the 2nd image content
</div>

<div class="item-3 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the 3rd image content
</div>


<div class="item-1 content-item">
    I am the content for item 1
</div>

<div class="item-2 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 2
</div>

<div class="item-3 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 3
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
$('.change-item').click(function(){
    var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
    $('.content-item').hide();
    $('.item-' + this_item).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. Please elaborate with complete HTML code. But, it sounds like CSS positioning issue. Try positioning the elements as absolute/fixed if you don't want them to move along with your divs.

Comment: all your divs dissappear thats what you are doing

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/3mJ3z/69/ just trying to fade in and out the DIV's, but the content and buttons jump around. pardon my ignorance..new to this stuff and just trying to learn. Tried the CSS positioning and it didn't help.